# Too long character string in knitr html output

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown

My function `bs.pi.gmp()` defined [here](http://stla.overblog.com/the-binary-splitting-with-the-r-gmp-package-application-to-gauss-hypergeometric-function) can produce very long character strings:

```
> bs.pi.gmp(8)
$Sn
Big Rational ('bigq') :
[1] 115056663317199981372832786803399641133848259535718238578854114440177847232763528127119686643465544336537363974090559640151844992619459739337642897335661405374200830442503779326745081494631228217510085926896107230240702464/73247346810369298651903071099557979072216039642432949710389234675732768750102001285974817825809831148661290123993641325086924401900965008305646606428886048721946203288377842830920059623434101646117412656625454480462852875

$eval.Sn
[1] "1.570796326794896557999"
```

When I run `bs.pi.gmp(8)` inside a RMarkdown document, then the string goes beyond the width screen. I have tried to solve that using `options(width=...)` or using `tidy` option in the chunk but that does not work. How to solve that ?

However when I simply copy-paste the html produced by knitr on [overblog](http://stla.overblog.com/the-binary-splitting-with-the-r-gmp-package-application-to-gauss-hypergeometric-function) then, as you can see, the rendering is perfect. This is surely due to an html option (in the header)  produced when the article is published on the blog, but what is this option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the overblog site, the container that the long string is in, has `word-wrap: break-word`, while in your example here, it doesn't. (`word-wrap` is set to its default, `normal`).

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Solution: apply the style `word-wrap: break-word` to wherever you put the string.
(Unfortunately, I am not well versed in RMarkdown and I'm not sure how you should do that exactly. But I *am* sure it will do the trick.)

Edit:
If you have full control over the CSS, all you need to do is add that property to the style for `pre code`.
So the complete style will read

```
pre code {
   display: block; padding: 0.5em;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That sounds nice, but I don't know where to put this code exactly. Here is a gist with the raw knitr html output: https://gist.github.com/stla/6258179 The long string is at line 461. Maybe could give me an idea about where to put the code ?

Comment: You can change the CSS at will, can you? Then put the new property in with the styles for `pre code`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I don't know exactly what is a CSS but I will try to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Ok I have put this code on line 58 and it works: http://pagist.github.io/?6258179 Thank you very much ! About the CSS I think you mean there should be an automatic way to do so, I will try to find it.

Comment: Ok I have find the CSS file: `markdown.css` in the `Rstudio/resources` directory. Perfecto !!